# How to run swiftlint for git diff files only

Tags: swift, git, version-control, swiftlint

I am working on an iOS Swift project. Git is being used for version controlling. I want to run `swiftlint` tool only for newly changed files. On other words, I want to check static issues only for the files that have been edited till last commit. If possible, I will add the script in `Build phase -> Run script`, so that every developer can find the static issues only for the files they are working on. Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding this below command in Build phase - run script will be helpful.

Below code will work for staged files

```
git diff --cached --name-only | grep "\.swift" | while read filename; do
    swiftlint lint --path "$filename";
done
```

For unstaged files you need to remove `--cached` argument

```
git diff --name-only | grep "\.swift" | while read filename; do
    swiftlint lint --path "$filename";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate through the items:

```
swiftlint lint --path $(git diff HEAD --name-only | grep "\.swift")
```

Also, `git diff HEAD` gives you **staged** and **unstaged** files.